Android Compose wont update state from Mutable State
I am currently trying to use a compose view outside of the MVVM and ViewModels but I cam having a real struggle with state updates.
Currently I have the Compose view rendering correctly and it is referencing the mutableState I created correctly but I cannot get the state to update.
This is my compose and state code. The composable Content function is called from the activity setContent{}
private var userState = mutableStateOf<List<GithubSearchUser>>(listOf())
private var loadingState = mutableStateOf(LoadingState.SUCCESS)

    @Composable
    fun Content() {
        TemplateProjectTheme {
            Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                topBar = {...}) { innerPadding ->
                when (loadingState.value) {
                    LoadingState.SUCCESS -> {
                            .padding(innerPadding)
                            .fillMaxSize()) {
                            GithubUsersList(
                                users = userState.value,
                                onItemClick = listUserClickRelay::send,
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    LoadingState.EMPTY -> {
                       //more compose code
                    }

I am updating the user state using a separate function that updates mutable state
fun updateUsers(users: List<GithubSearchUser>) {
   this.userState.value = users
}

The compose code correctly reads the initial state but any updates set to the mutable state don't update or trigger a recompose. In the debugger I can see the state being updated but no recompositing is happening. This issue happens for both the user list and loading state.
This is driving me mad for 2 days now.
I have tried multiple things that all failed

Using delegates with the by keyword and importing the setValue compose extension functions.
Moving the mutableStateOf to a remember function in the compose block


Why don't you move your userState and loadingState into your Composable?

Something went wrong when copy&pasting your code here: What is the first that happens in the LoadingState.SUCCESS case? It shouldn't be .padding(innerPadding).

Also, how is updateUsers() called? Some Button's onClick lambda or something else originating from Compose code, or is this called from outside of a composable?

The issue is not the code you have above. The issue is most likely in the caller of updateUsers(). Since you didn't include the code I can only guess. My guess is updateUsers() is being called with the same instance of a MutableList<T> that was modified to contain the new state users. Since the mutableStateOf() receives the same instance of list every time, it doesn't consider that a change so it doesn't invalidate the readers.
There are two solutions to this. This easiest is to always call updateUsers() with a new list instead of the list changes instead of the backing list directly. Alternately, you can use a mutableStateListOf() instead of a mutuableListOf().

I had an issue in my dependency injection, there were two compose instances, one being rendered and one being updated.
There was no issue with the state being updated.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
